# How to document a flask-restplus response with list of strings

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restplus

I am documenting my response models, and need to show the api returns list of string.

```
["user1","user2"]
```

but the model requires a dictionary(json) format, as follow:

```
ns.response(200,'Success', NS.model("my_get_model",[{
    "name": fields.String(example="user1"),
}]))
```

I have tried following codes but none of them work:

```
ns = Namespace('My Apis')


ns.response(200,'Success', [ns.model("my_get_model",
    fields.String(example="user1")
)])
```

or

```
ns.response(200,'Success', ["user1"])
```

or

```
ns.response(200,'Success', ns.model("my_get_model",fields.List(fields.String(example="user1"))))
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you need: https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/65

Try simply passing in `fields.List` without wrapping a model.

```
ns.response(200, 'Success', fields.List(fields.String(example="user1")))
```

FYI, `flask-restx` is a fork of `flask-restplus` and it should have more updated features since `flask-restplus` is no longer being maintained due to the developers no able to contact `flask-restplus`'s project owner.

Comment: How to document it in swagger?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use doc decorator instead:

```
@api.doc(responses={200: """['s1', 's2', 's3']"""})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example, How to use model with the response:

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, fields
Import <other packges>

NS = Namespace(name="Api Name", description="Api description")

# Model
MY_MODEL = NS.model(
    "mymodel",
    {
        "message": fields.String(example="some string"),
        "some_code": fields.String(example="SOME_CODE_101"),
        "some_list_params": fields.List(fields.String)
    },
)

# For controller

@NS.route("hello")
class Hello(Resource):
    """Some API"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Hello, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @NS.vendor(private=True)
    @NS.response(200, "My API", MY_MODEL)
    @marshal_with(MY_MODEL)
    def get(self):

        return {some_code: "SOME_CODE_101", "message": "Some message", "some_list_params": []}, 200
```

Here you can use the `fields.List`

Answer (score 1):

Found in https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger.html

Tested with flask-restx==0.2.0

```
    dbsystem_fields = ns.model('DbSystem', {
        'id': fields.String,
        'name': fields.String,
        'engine': fields.String,
        'version': fields.String
    })
    
    @ns.route('/systems')
    class Systems(Resource):
        @ns.marshal_with(dbsystem_fields, as_list=True)
    
    @api.route('/systems')
    class Systems(Resource):
        @api.marshal_with(dbsystem_fields, as_list=True)
        # @api.response(200, "Success", [dbsystem_fields]) # Also works
        def get(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure of you model is wrong, you need to write in this way:

```
ns.model("my_get_model",{
    "name": fields.String(example="user1")
})
```

**UPDATE:**
Showing a list like a value of a key in your JSON you needs to use `fields.List` instead of `fields.String`

```
ns.model("my_get_model",{
    "name": fields.List(example="user1")
})
```

Comment: no, this model says I am returning a json object {"name":"user1"}. there is no KeyValue pairs. it is simple list of strings. also I am not able to modify the api. just need to document it

Comment: Oh I got it, use `fields.List` instead of `fields.String`, I think you can't you show more than one example, but you string will be wrapped in square brackets

Comment: I think you still did not get my question, your update says this model ```{"name":["user1"]}``` by api response is ```["user1"]```, api's response is not a json

Comment: I think you can "cheat" passing it like a description in your response, for example `"['user1']"`, I see the files of RESTPlus and I can´t found a good solution for your problem

Comment: @AxelAnaya I'm facing the same issue. I'd like to add multiple examples in fields.List. Has anyone managed to figure out how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**At first, flask-restplus is moved to flask-restx. [Check it out](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).**

### Step 1

Define model as an instance or as an attribute to api or ns.

```
model = model("ModelName",{"name": fields.String(example="user1")})
```

### Step 2

Define instance of Api or Namespace.

```
api = Api(app) #or
ns = Namespace('NamespaceName')
```

### Step 3

Append response decorator to endpoint.

```
@api.response(200, model, as_list=True) #or ns
def get(self):
    return 'Your response'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your model like this, when you are using **model**, you have to use **enum** instead of **List**

```
ns.model("my_get_model",{
    "name": fields.String(description="your description", enum=["user1", "user2"])
})
```

Hope it'll help you, let me know